# Trying to convert JWT to JWE but facing some error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, jwt, jwe

I want to convert JWT into JWE but all my tries have failed. I am trying React JS. I also tried in Express JS but faced the same error. I have used Node-Jose for my tries.

```
const createJWE = async () => {
    // Payload to be included in the JWT
    const payload = {
        idToken: 'token',
    };

    try {
        // Sign the JWT
        const jwt = await jose.JWS.createSign({ format: 'compact' }, { key: rsaPublicKey }).update(JSON.stringify(payload)).final();

       // Encrypt the JWT to create a JWE
       const jwe = await jose.JWE.createEncrypt({ format: 'compact' }, { key: rsaPublicKey }).update(jwt).final();
        
       console.log(jwe);
   } catch (error) {
       console.error('JWE Creation Error:', error);
   }
}
createJWE();
```

The output

[image]

Comment: The `jwt` variable is a `Promise<string>` as you haven't used `await` on that line.

Comment: That line const jwt = jose.JWS.createSign({ format: 'compact' }, { key: rsaPublicKey }).update(JSON.stringify(payload)).final(); is just put here because given string is not JWT, In actual I am trying to convert idToken from firebase that is already a JWT, so please skip that line, I just put here as I put 'token' on the place of idToken

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the source for [`createSign(...)`](https://github.com/cisco/node-jose/blob/37db9e5371dc9a0557767a6a0190e2b0ab5cf3b6/lib/jws/sign.js#L284), `key` in the second argument is expected to be a JWK, either as an object, or as a [JSON string](https://github.com/cisco/node-jose/blob/37db9e5371dc9a0557767a6a0190e2b0ab5cf3b6/lib/jwk/keystore.js#L289-L292). So your error is derived from the value of `rsaPublicKey` being in the wrong format.

As the value used for `key` is a JWK object/string, it should look similar to:

```json
{
  "kty": "RSA",
  "n": "qPfgaTEWEP3S9w0tgsicURfo-nLW09_0KfOPinhYZ4ouzU-3xC4pSlEp8Ut9FgL0AgqNslNaK34Kq-NZjO9DAQ==",
  "e": "AQAB"
}
```

Based on the error message, your `rsaPublicKey` probably contains the content of a PEM file (as the error complains the first character is a minus, but the second is not a number):

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBAKj34GkxFhD90vcNLYLInFEX6Ppy1tPf
9Cnzj4p4WGeKLs1Pt8QuKUpRKfFLfRYC9AIKjbJTWit+CqvjWYzvQwECAwEAAQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

To import a key in this format, you need to bring the key in using `keystore.add` (from `JWK.createKeyStore()`) or `JWK.asKey` and specifying the format.

```js
const publicKey = await jose.JWK.asKey(rsaPublicKey, "pem"); // "pem" derives the key type

// usage:
const jwe = await jose.JWE
  .createEncrypt({ format: 'compact' }, publicKey)
  .update(/* ... */)
  .final();
```

Ultimately you should be using a private key to sign instead.

```js
const privateKey = await jose.JWK.asKey(rsaPrivateKey, "pem"); // "pem" derives the key type

// usage:
const jwe = await jose.JWE
  .createEncrypt({ format: 'compact' }, privateKey)
  .update(/* ... */)
  .final();
```

---

**Note:** Above keys were obtained from https://phpseclib.com/docs/rsa-keys